Is it possible to change the type of a property in an interface depending on a nested property?
I have the following two interfaces:
    export interface IQuestion {
        type: 'single' | 'sort'
        prompt: string;
        options: {
            id: string,
            text: string
        }[]
    }
    export type ICurrentQuestion  = {
        correctAnswerId: string | string[],
        question: IQuestion, 
        extraData?: IResultsAnswerData
    }

I want it so correctAnswerId will be of string[] if the type of question is sort. I do not want to move type to the top level as what's in question is what's sent to the client so I would have to duplicate type at both levels. From my research it seems like what I want to do isn't possible, but I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around what the best way to be typesafe here would be.
Thank you in advanced to the smart people out there!:)

You can use a union like this, but it isn't clear from this question what the use case is. Could you write some code as a [mre] that shows how you'd use such a type?

@jcalz This worked! If you submit as answer I'll accept!

If you want a type to be either this or that, then you should make it a union type.
One of your types has a correctAnswerId of string and a question.type property of "single":
interface SingleCurrentQuestion {
   correctAnswerId: string,
   question: SingleQuestion,
   extraData?: IResultsAnswerData
}
interface SingleQuestion {
   type: 'single'
   prompt: string;
   options: {
      id: string,
      text: string
   }[]
}

And the other has a correctAnswerId of string[] and a question.type property of "sort":
interface SortCurrentQuestion {
   correctAnswerId: string[],
   question: SortQuestion,
   extraData?: IResultsAnswerData
}    
interface SortQuestion {
   type: 'sort'
   prompt: string;
   options: {
      id: string,
      text: string
   }[]
}

And so the type you want is the union of those:
type CurrentQuestion =
   SortCurrentQuestion | SingleCurrentQuestion;

Note that because it's a union it can't be an interface directly, and can only be a type alias. But it shouldn't matter for most use cases.
Also, note that because the "sort" vs "single" property is nested inside the question property, the CurrentQuestion is a union but not a discriminated union, so you won't be able to write if (q.question.type === "single") { ⋯ } else { ⋯ } and expect q to be narrowed inside those blocks.  There's a longstanding open feature request at microsoft/TypeScript#18758 to support that sort of nested discriminant, but for now it's not part of the language.
Playground link to code
